# Django unit testing for Verbose_name

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models

Below is a class in model.py

```
class UnitUsers(models.Model):
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    mark = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    submit = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.unit) + " - " + str(self.user)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Unit User')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Unit Users')
```

Tried to write test case for verbose_name as below

```
class UnitUsersTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        unit = Unit.objects.create(name='Python', 
                                   start='2018-10-25 14:30:59', 
                                   end='2017-10-25 14:30:59',
                                   description='111', deleted='False')
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_superuser(username='admin', 
                                                  email='admin@decent.mark',
                                                  password='password')
        UnitUsers.objects.create(unit=unit, user=user, create='False', 
                                 mark='False', submit='True')


    def test_verbose_name(self):
        unit_user = UnitUsers.objects.get(id=1)
        field_label = unit_user._meta.get_field('user').verbose_name
        self.assertEquals(field_label, 'Unit User')
```

Getting error as

### FAIL: test_verbose_name (decentmark.tests.test_model.UnitUsersTest)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Prabhanjan\Documents\GitHub\decentmark\decentmark\tests\test_model.py", line 54, in test_verbose_name
    self.assertEquals(field_label, 'Unit User')
AssertionError: 'user' != 'Unit User'
- user
+ Unit User

---

Ran 11 tests in 0.505s

FAILED (failures=1)

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow!!! In order to get your a better answer, and your answer don't get deleted later on, you would have to read and follow some basic rules and conventions that will help everyone to communicate and help better. Please go to https://stackoverflow.com/help and read about the topic "What topics can I ask about here?", and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?".

Comment: Do not write tests for django internals, django is already well tested and you should trust developers working on django source code. write tests for your own logic instead of writing tests for django

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the Meta Class to

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Unit User"
    verbose_name_plural = "Unit Users"
```

Then what your test should look like

```
def test_verbose_name_plural(self):
    #unituser is the Class UnitUsers(model.Models)
    unitusers = UnitUsers.objects.get(id=1)
    verbose_name_plural = unitusers._meta.verbose_name_plural
    self.assertEquals(verbose_name_plural, "Unit Users"
```